# When a record is locked in Oracle, can we know which record is locked?

Tags: oracle, locking

When a record is locked ,can we know which one is locked?

How can I get the record rowid or something else info?

---

I can get some info by this sql

```
SELECT c.ROW_WAIT_OBJ#,c.ROW_WAIT_FILE#,c.ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#,c.ROW_WAIT_ROW#
   FROM v$locked_object a, dba_objects b, v$session c    
WHERE a.object_id = b.object_id    
    AND a.SESSION_ID = c.sid(+)
```

I found a method in web to get rowid by using function `DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_CREATE()`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can only see locks that some process is waiting for, not those that are held by a transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - v$lock shows you the locks held by a transaction

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: You are right. I was referring to the fact that you cannot see which *rows* have been locked - I should have been more clear.

Comment: Oracle (on contrary from other databases) does not have any shared structure for locks. This makes the database scalable, but in the other hand you can not see all locks. Locks are stored in database blocks directly. In the moment when somebody gets blocked a structure "holder-waiter" is created. Then you will see this pair in `V$LOCK`.

Answer (score 14):

You can't really list all rows that are being **locked** by a session. However, once a session is being **blocked** by another, you can find which session/row is blocking it.

Oracle doesn't maintain a list of individual row locks. Rather, locks are registered directly inside the rows themselves -- think of it as an extra column.

You can find which session has acquired a lock on an object through the [`V$LOCK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_2027.htm#i1407629) view, but this will only list general information, not at the row level.

With this view you can also find if a session is being blocked by another. In that case, if a session is **blocked** by another session, the row information is displayed in the `V$SESSION` information.

You can retrieve the rowid, let's build an example with 2 sessions:

```
SESSION1> create table test as select * from all_objects;

Table created

SESSION1> select rowid from test where object_name = 'TEST' for update;

ROWID
------------------
AAMnFEAAaAAALTDAAz

/* setting identifiers to help with identifying this session later */
SESSION2> exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('012345');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SESSION2> select 1 from test where object_name = 'TEST' for update;
/*  this will block */
```

Session 2 is now waiting on Session 1. We can discover the **blocking** row with:

```
SESSION1> SELECT o.object_name,
       2         dbms_rowid.ROWID_CREATE (1,
       3                                  s.ROW_WAIT_OBJ#,
       4                                  s.ROW_WAIT_FILE#,
       5                                  s.ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#,
       6                                  s.ROW_WAIT_ROW#) rid
       7     FROM dba_objects o, v$session s
       8    WHERE o.object_id = s.row_wait_obj#
       9      AND s.client_info = '012345';

OBJECT_NAME     RID
--------------- ------------------
TEST            AAMnFEAAaAAALTDAAz
```

For further reading: a [description of the process by Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:53140949357315).

Answer (score 4):

You can find all tables locks in an Oracle database by running the following query

```
select
   c.owner,
   c.object_name,
   c.object_type,
   b.sid,
   b.serial#,
   b.status,
   b.osuser,
   b.machine
from
   v$locked_object a ,
   v$session b,
   dba_objects c
where
   b.sid = a.session_id
and
   a.object_id = c.object_id;
```

Comment: what is the point ?

Comment: how to unlock the record this needs to be told

Comment: question was to find out the locked objects not to resolve those locks. to resolve that locks you need to find the locked session and release.